# Angular ngrx@effect basic question : Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to figure out how @ngrx/effects works, but I am having some problems in this easy example below my error and my stackbliz code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects%2Ftask.effects.ts

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Action'

thank

[image]

Comment: Add a return in `map()`; `return data`

Comment: thank you but nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong just to start with

- The error you are getting is because you need `pipe(map(data => ...)` from `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`.
- Then you need to add `dispatch: false` since you are not returning any actions, otherwise you will get stuck in an endless loop.

### Two options

An effect should either return an action or `dispatch: false`

#### Option 1: No dispatched action

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false }) 
loadTasks$: Observable<void> = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(fromActions.ADD_TASK),
   switchMap(() => this.taskService.GetTasks().pipe(
      map(data => {             
        console.log(data);        
      })
   ) 
));
```

#### Option 2: Dispatch action

```
@Effect()
loadTasks$: Observable<void> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromActions.ADD_TASK),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.taskService.GetTasks().pipe(
      map(
        (data: Task[]) => new SomeActionYouGot(data);
      ),
      catchError(error =>
        of(new SomeOtherActionThatIndicatesFailFor(data))
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: thank you but doesn't work 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects%2Ftask.effects.ts

Comment: No but you cant return data in an effects, that's why it's "not working" as you expect it to. I actually just solved the error that was raised and gave a hint about what you can do. 

But instead of trying to return the data you need to dispatch a new action with the new data you recieved. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

In RXJS, inside map operator, you need to return values will be received when observer subscribes.

```
    @Effect() 
  loadTasks$: Observable<Task[]> = this.actions$
    .ofType(fromActions.ADD_TASK).pipe(
    switchMap(() => ({this.taskService.GetTasks().map(data => {
            return data; })            
      })) 

    );
```

Comment: Updated the answer. please check.

Comment: still error ...you can see directly on the project link

Comment: Typo error. updated. https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects%2Ftask.effects.ts

Comment: if you take a look to the console i have another error 
//console Error: this.actions$.ofType(...).switchMap is not a function

Comment: Error: switchMap is not defined :-)

Comment: Add import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: _this.taskService.GetTasks(...).map is not a function

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects%2Ftask.effects.ts

Comment: quen i click de button save ; i have this error; 
ERROR
Error: _this.taskService.GetTasks(...).map is not a function

Comment: never mind we are out of topics, you already solde the problem , the think is that i haven't understood how effects works...and i was trying to make it works a easy example

Comment: sorry but doesn't work, at the end it doesn't return anything.